# Is there something missing in this code ? I am unable to post through axios post request

Tags: reactjs, axios, mern

So I have setup a form for taking user details and setting the data to the state. Then I am passing the state data to the database through onSubmit function. I am using axios.post request to the local host server. 
My get request seems to be working fine however the data is not being posted after submitting the form.

My code looks something like this. (I am abstracting unnecessary code.)

UserForm.jsx

```
class UserForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "",
      contact: "",
      company: "",
      mail: "",
      key: {
        wedding: false,
        MICE: false,
        corporate: false
      },
      app_no: "",
      items: "",
      isLoaded: false
    };
  }

handleSubmit = e => {
    console.log("Submitted");
    e.preventDefault();
    const users = {
      name: this.state.name,
      contact: this.state.contact,
      company: this.state.company,
      mail: this.state.mail,
      key: this.state.key,
      app_no: this.state.app_no
    };
    axios
      .post(
        "http://localhost:5000/api/items",
        { users },
        {
          headers: {
            "content-type": "application/json"
          }
        }
      )

      .then(console.log("Axios post is working"))
      .then(res => {
        console.log("Something: " + res);
        console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    console.log("Users; " + users.name);
  };


componentDidMount() {
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/items/", {
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json"
      }
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          items: json
        });
      });
    console.log(this.state.items);
  }
```

My form seems to be working fine and giving all the items on console.
This is my items.js file:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

// Item model
const Item = require("../../models/Item");

// Routes
// @get API item get all items
// make a get req
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  Item.find().then(items => res.json(items));
});

// @get Api item POST all items
// make a post req
// create an item
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  const newItem = new Item({
    name: req.body.name,
    contact_no: req.body.contact_no,
    company_name: req.body.company_name,
    key: req.body.key
  });

  newItem.save().then(item => res.json(item));
});

// @del api item.
// delete request
router.delete("/:id", (req, res) => {
  Item.findById(req.params.id)
    .then(item => item.remove().then(() => res.json({ success: true })))
    .catch(err => res.status(404).json({ success: false }));
});

module.exports = router;
```

Is there something I am missing in the code. I have gone through most of the axios documentation and can't seem to find the problem.

```
server.js
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();
const items = require("./routes/api/items"); // Contains all the api routes

// Body Parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// DB config
const db = require("./config/keys").mongoURI;

mongoose
  .connect(db, { useNewUrlParser: true })
  .then(() => console.log("Mongo is laoded"))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

app.use("/api/items", items); // redirecting api routes to items

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log("Server started"));
```

Let me know if I should post more code..
Edit: I am not getting "console.log("Something: " + res);
        console.log(res.data);" response on console.
My console prints :

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
Submitted
UserForm.jsx:56 Axios post is working
UserForm.jsx:70 Users; someuser
```

Comment: I think I am not getting the response back from res

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you'd ever be able to get your records through `req.body.name`, as your POST request seems to be putting that under `req.body.users.name`, so basically you'd want to fetch your data from `req.body.users`

Comment: So I should replace `req.body.users.name` with `req.body.user` ?

Comment: Not sure I understand how you mean.

Comment: I mean, if I'm to suggest things to change, there are probably a lot of them, however with regard to your question, if you replace that, but you'd also need to update how you're passing the user data to the backend from your frontend. If you're proceeding with what you have, all I'm saying is you'd need to access the user data through `req.body.users` instead of `req.body` in your backend. So technically, you could just have `const newItem = new Item(req.body.users)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is beacause your second .then in axios.post
Put everything in a single `.then`

Try this:

```js
.then((res) => {
console.log("Axios post is working")
console.log("Something: " + res);
console.log(res.data);
})
```

Comment: Plus the response is not printed on the console.

Comment: @ArjunKashyap Are you following the MERN youtube series, right?
Have you tried doing the post using postman? to check what is your response.
Also check chrome developers tools to check in network tab what is happening, you can check the response there

Comment: Yeah I was initially following it. i tried posting the request through post master. It failed. `Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to http://localhost:5000/api/items.`

Comment: and you are able to use the get Method? Quite extrange. Please provide info about what you get when try to use method post, in your server js and in chrome developer tools network tab